# Child component doesn't update when the result of delete action is being received form the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The `parent component` dispatches the action to retrieve as well as delete item.
The child component contains the list of items and contains the delete button.

Here's my plan of the the sequence of events

```
**Retrieve Address List:** 
Parent fetches list > Pass to Child > Display in Child <br> [ ->✓ Works well]

**Delete and Address** 
Child invokes delete action > Action dispatched via parent > Result received in parent > Result sent to child via props > Child re-renders <br> [ -> ✘ Object is deleted in server but component desn't re-render]
```

To my knowledge, the sequence of events should update the component state finally which forces to re-render it. What am I missing?

**`Parent Component`**

```
class Parent extends React.Component
{
    componentWillMount()
    {
        store.dispatch(fetchShippingAddresses());
    }

    deleteAddress(address_id)
    {
        store.dispatch(deleteShippingAddress(address_id));
    }

    render()
    {
      let shippingAddresses = this.props.shippingAddressesList;
      let deleteShippingAddressData = this.props.deleteShippingAddressData;

      return (

         <AddressList 
             shippingAddresses={shippingAddresses}
             deleteAddresses ={(address_id) => this.deleteAddress(address_id)}
             deleteShippingAddressData: this.props.deleteShippingAddressData

      )
    }

}

function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        shippingAddressesList : state.shippingAddressesList,
        deleteShippingAddressData : state.deleteShippingAddressData
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DashboardBody);
```

**`Child Component`**

```
class AddressList extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state =
        {
            shippingAddresses: [],
            deleteShippingAddressData: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)
    {
        this.state.shippingAddresses !== nextProps.shippingAddresses &&
            this.setState({ shippingAddresses: nextProps.shippingAddresses });

        this.state.deleteShippingAddressData !==  nextProps.deleteShippingAddressData &&
        this.setState({ deleteShippingAddressData: nextProps.deleteShippingAddressData});
    }

    render()
    {
      addresses = this.state.shippingAddresses;
      return (

       <div >
            { addresses && addresses.data.map( (address, i) =>

                <p key={i}>
                  {address.address_name}
                  <button onClick={ event => this.props.deleteAddress(address.id) }>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </p>

            )}
       </div>

     )
    }
}
```

**`Delete Action`**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function deleteShippingAddress(address_id)
{
    return function(dispatch)
    {
        dispatch(destroyShippingAddressSuccess(false));
        dispatch(destroyShippingAddressError(null));

        const request = axios
        ({
            url: `http://api.stagingapp.io/location/v1/shipping/address/${address_id}`,
            method: "delete",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token') }
        })

        .then(function(response)
        {
            destroyShippingAddressSuccess(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error)
        {
            dispatch(destroyShippingAddressError(error));
            console.log(error)
        });

        return { type: 'DESTROY_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SUCCESS', payload: request }

    };

}

function destroyShippingAddressSuccess(deleteShippingAddressData)
{
    return {  type: 'DESTROY_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SUCCESS', deleteShippingAddressData};
}
function destroyShippingAddressError(deleteShippingAddressError)
{
    return {  type: 'DESTROY_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ERROR', deleteShippingAddressError };
}

export default deleteShippingAddress;
```

**`Deletion Reducer`**

```
export default function deleteShippingAddressReducer
    (state = { deleteShippingAddressError:'', deleteShippingAddressData:'' }, action)

        {
            switch (action.type)
            {
                case 'DESTROY_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_SUCCESS':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { deleteShippingAddressData: action.deleteShippingAddressData});

                case 'DESTROY_SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ERROR':
                    return Object.assign({}, state, { deleteShippingAddressError: action.deleteShippingAddressError });

                default: return state;
            }
        }
    //
//
```

Comment: I assume deleteShippingAddressDetails  is an action. In that case you should have it in the mapDispatchToProps and not in mapStateToProps

Comment: What is `addresses` in `AddressList.render`?

Comment: No, deleteShippingAddressDetails is a state that's listed in the reducers, that's updated with error or success message after the delete action.

Comment: @OrB, I'm sorry, I missed `addresses = this.state.shippingAddresses` in the render function. Question updated ☑ .

Comment: @anonym Is there a reason you're assigning `shippingAddresses` to the state, instead of rendering directly from `props`? Is `componentWillReceiveProps` being called with the addresses?

Comment: If you mutate the state inside your reducer the reference to shippingAddresses will stay the same. Make sure you use Object.assing({}, shippingAddresses) or incase of an array you would use .concat or something that produces a new array reference. Do not use methods such as splice or push. For more info on array mutation: http://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Comment: Please post the part of the reducer that handles these actions.

Comment: @OrB, Yes, it's not proper. I could simply do `let addresses = this.props.shippingAddresses.data;` in the `render()` and display them, that works fine. I'm just experimenting if assigning and changing the current state of the component would force it to reload.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I've updated the question with reducer and actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer, you are using `action.deleteShippingAddress` but in your action creator you are creating an object with `destroyShippingAddressData`. Rename it to match the reducer or action, depending on which name you would like to keep.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately, that wasn't what was preventing the component from re-rendering. There's something more that I'm missing out.

Comment: did you get it working? let me knw how you fixed it thanks